# Camelot not detecting table within table

Tags: python, data-extraction, python-camelot

I have observed that camelot is not detecting nested tables in the sample document I have.
In the image attached, I'm getting only one table extracted as whole. Is there anyway using which we can detect the inner tables as well?

[image]

Comment: Please explain better what is the desired output and show what you tried.
In any case, you can manually specify a list of table_areas, each one for every tables (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-areas).

Comment: I want the inner tables, i.e. Fee Schedule table to be detected along with the other tables like Contract Timelines, etc. Now when I pass the pdf to camelot, it just gives me one whole table below the line 'The contract is extracted between ABCD ....'.  I know we can pass table_regions or table_areas but I don't to opt for that. I have other pdfs which differ from this. I want a generalised solution, if there is one that.

Comment: Ok. You can try to pass `table_regions` (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-regions), specifying a fixed restricted part of the page. Maybe if you exclude outer lines, the detection would be more similar to the desired result... Let me know if this works...

Comment: Yes. This solution works. I have tried it with table_regions specified. But there is no way we will get it without specifying table_regiogs, right? As in I have many other pdfs too which have straightforward tables unlike this one. I wanted a generalised solution for that reason. I guess I have to check the lines on the pdf and then apply table_regions accordingly.

Comment: If you are lucky, the table region is the same in the various documents.

Maybe, I'm going to write an answer, starting from my last comment...

Comment: Yes. I need to look into all the sample pdfs I have and come to a conclusion. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: If useful, please accept/upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically extract internal tables only, you can try passing [`table_regions` parameter](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-regions), specifying a fixed limited part of the page.

> When **table_regions** is specified, Camelot will only analyze the
> specified regions to look for tables.